# Laravel Eloquent load relationship of the pivot

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, has-and-belongs-to-many

In my website I have User, Roles and Permissions.

Each user belongs to many Roles (eg. User.php) and pivot table called 'role_user'

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}
```

and each Role belongs to many Permissions (eg. Role.php) and pivot table called 'permission_role'

```
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class);
}
```

I want to somehow access the User permission but I can't seem to figure it out. Basically I need something like this on the User.php

```
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->roles()->permissions();
}
```

Is this possible? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Look into eager loading. You’ll be able to access nested relationships using the dot notation.

Comment: @adam, I already tried that but it doesn't work. Could you please provide a working example?

Comment: Try `User::with(['roles', 'roles.permissions'])->find($youruserid);`

Comment: @adam, i tried that, but it returns the names of the users... so it isn't working... I made

Comment: if you don't want the names of the users use a select clause `select('column1', 'column2'...`

Answer (score 1):

Laravel has no native support for a direct relationship.

I created a package for this case: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep

You can use it like this:

```php
class User extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function permissions() {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(
            Permission::class, ['role_user', Role::class, 'permission_role']
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using your results in JSON format, this should be very easy if you implement [Eloquent Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources)

Define three resources as follows:

(Note: to easily define a resource like below, do:

```
php artisan make:resource UserRes
```

Then modify the toArray function as you desire.
)

**UserRes**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class UserRes extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        $user = parent::toArray($request);
        $user["roles"] = RolesRes::collection($this->roles);
        return $user;
    }
}
```

**RolesRes**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class RolesRes extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        $res =  parent::toArray($request);
        $res["permissions"] = $this->permissions;
        return $res;
    }
}
```

**PermissionsRes:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class PermissionsRes extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        $perm = parent::toArray($request);
        return $perm;
    }
}
```

In my app, here is a screenshot of a sample of results when fetching a single user. Take note of the nesting of multiple roles under which are multiple permissions.
[Screenshot of a JSON response when querying a single user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mg2Zx.png)